# Can't install Composer Dependency management

Tags: php, openssl, wamp, composer-php

Trying to install Composer dependency management tool on Win7/32 + WampServer 2.2 via the Setup Installer and I am getting the following message:

The openssl extension is missing, which will reduce the security and stability of Composer. If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

So here is what I did...

From my Wamp icon in Tray, clicked php > php extensions > php_openssl

This showed that task was completed by placing a check mark beside the extension
I then restarted WampServer

Then from the Wamp icon in tray, I clicked php > php.ini and searched for openssl to verifiy  if it was commented) out. It was not.

Then on the Apache > apachi2.2.22 > php.ini and did the same thing.
Then I did restart my Wamp server and tried to install Composer again. but the problem is same.

Please advise.

Comment: PHP CLI may well use a different php.ini file to the Webserver SAPI

Comment: Execute `php -i | grep "Configuration File"` (or Windows equivalent) from the command line to find the ini file that is being used for the command line SAPI

Comment: I executed this, here is the result :

Configuration File <php.ini> Path => C:\windows

Loaded configuration File => D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini

Actually I don't know what to do now.
Thank you

Comment: So edit D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini and enable the openssl extension by uncommenting it, save the file, then `php -m` from the command line will list the installed modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WampServer, and most PHP environments I suspect, the PHP CLI ( Command Line Interface ) uses a different php.ini file.

Apache uses `\wamp\bin\php\{phpversion}\phpForApache.ini` and this is what you are actually editing when you use the wampmanager menus.

The PHP CLI uses `\wamp\bin\php\{phpversion}\php.ini`. So manually edit that file and uncomment the extensions that you require when using the PHP CLI.